# Victory bonus for November and December

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

After finishing October, we had found

> the virologist, the immunologist and patient 0

The event cards then told us to

> consider all searches complete (-> the paranoid soldier) and open the relevant boxes (which gave us vaccine centers, etc.).

But still, a possible victory bonus for the start of November and December is

> to advance the search markers by 1.

However, this seems now utterly useless.

Am I missing something ?

We're playing with the French blue edition (if it changes anything).

Answer (score 1):

For November, I believe it is simply that you may not have yet finished the searches; so you might still have to do those in November. You just finished them sooner. But you can also just use the other option if you don’t need the search bonus.

For December,

> a new search mission is introduced; and the bonus can help with that new search.